# Prove n-element complete, or nearly complete, binary tree has height log_2 (n)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have the problem:

Prove n-element complete, or nearly complete, binary tree has height log_2(n)

I have not done inductions in a while, and I am stuck with even how to begin the problem. How do I go about tackling this or even start it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Inductive proofs are like recursion. You have to "prove" a base case then prove the next most complex case in terms of the previous.

For example, the base case for a complete balanced tree of height one is one item:

```
A
```

The case for a height two tree is three items, double the number of items at the previous level (1) plus the sum of all preceding levels (1):

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

The case for a height three tree is seven items, double the number of items at the previous level (2) plus the sum of all preceding levels (3):

```
    _A_
   /   \
  B     C
 / \   / \
D   E F   G
```

Because each level doubles the capacity and adds one, the number of items `n` in a tree on height `h` is (roughly) `2h`.

And, because the reverse function of powers is logarithms, we can say that the height of the tree `h` is therefore (roughly) `log2n`.

Comment: although the logic is corrrect, i don't think this can count as a proof by induction. Looks more like a direct proof.

Comment: My understanding was that induction _is_ one form of direct proof, though admittedly I haven't done formal proofs for almost thirty years. Advancing age, and a rather large quantity of various spirits over that time, may well have dulled my memories :-)